# How do you take an array, 2 numbers and you get a return value of 4.375?

Tags: c++, function

Why does it return 4.375? I'm having a hard time understanding what is going on in the first return, like how do you take an array and 2 other numbers and get 1 number.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
    float f(int a[], int i,int j){
        if(i<j){
            int k = (i+j)/2;
            return (f(a,i,k)+f(a,k+1,j))/2;
        }
        else 
        return a[i];
    }
int main(){
    int a[]={8,3,4,7,5,6,1};
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return  f(a,0,6);
}
```

Comment: Try figuring out which values are being averaged. Execute the function on paper and you will understand why it returns what it returns.

Comment: Is this a question about recursion?  Are you confused by the function calling itself?

Comment: The first return takes two numbers - `f(a,i,k)` and `f(a,k+1,j)` - and divides their sum with two. It works exactly like it would if you called a different function twice.

Comment: @FelixCastor yeah, that part is the most confusing, "return (f(a,i,k)+f(a,k+1,j))/2;", like where does "a" come in play in the function. I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around it. And if the function is calling itself wouldn't that mean it would repeat that to the end of time?

Comment: `a` is a parameter for the function. It doesn't call itself when `i  >= j` (i.e. when it takes the `else` branch), which will happen eventually since the second and third argument are "closer" in every call. (The big secret of recursive functions is that there is nothing special about recursive functions.)

Comment: @molbdnilo i think I'm getting the grasp, so "a" in this case does nothing an means nothing, and in the first number in return "j" is replaced by "k"  and  new "k" is the acctuall numeber, is this right or am i going off rails?

Comment: You should take a look at the recursive solution to the Fibonacci sequence.  It's easier to follow than this algorithm.  `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2);`  Recursion is a tough hurdle to overcome imo.  Takes a bit to get the hang of.

Comment: Everything means exactly the same thing as it would if the function did not recurse - `a` is the input array, `i` is the starting index, and `j` is the ending index. `k` is the midpoint of the index interval. Imagine that the recursive calls don't say `f` but `g`, and that you know that the function `g` will return a number but you have no idea how it is implemented. (I suspect that you're trying to picture this by thinking about several function calls at once or by thinking in terms of a loop.)

Comment: @molbdnilo so the `i` and `j` never change and when functions recurse it always takes it as `i=0` and `j=6`, so in the first "loop" state in `f1` would be `f(a,0,3)` and state in `f2` would be `f(a,4,6)` so all together is `return (f(a,0,3)+f(a,3+1,6))/2`. If so far I'm on the right track, then it would "loop" until `else` condition is met and it will take `a[i]` as numbers respectively. Which means for `f1=8` since in `f(a,i,k)`  `i` is always 0 and 'f2=a[k]'. Is this how this would work or am I just to dumb to understand this. ;-;

Comment: `i` is not always 0 - it has the value passed to it in that particular call. *Inside* the `f(a,0,3)` call, `i` is 0 and `j` is 3; *inside* the `f(a,4,6)` call, `i` is 4 and `j` is 6, but that doesn't matter to the calling function. Every function call is independent from the others and has completely separate `i` and `j` variables. (Again: just like non-recursive functions.)

Comment: @molbdnilo oooooo i was on a right track. As other comment mentioned I tried to write it out on a paper and got somewhere i guess, but it's still not clear to me when does it actually returne `f1` and `f2` values so it can execute `return (f(a,0,3)+f(a,3+1,6))/2`. I guess what I'm trying to say is when does `f(a,i,k)` and `f(a,k+1,j)` become an number so `(f(a,0,3)+f(a,3+1,6))/2` can be executed. sorry if i'm frustrating you with my dumb questions

Comment: It sounds like you're either trying to picture the entire "tree" of calls at once, or thinking of it as a single function call. The function returns `a[i]` when there is a single number in the interval (`i == j`), otherwise it performs two function calls to compute the values for the two halves, and then computes their average. Again, it works in *exactly* the same way as if the function didn't call itself recursively, there is absolutely no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is proving tricky: there is nothing special about recursive functions. Nothing at all.

Remove the `i` and `j` parameters and encode them as function names instead; `f(a, 0, 0)` becomes `f_0_0(a)`, `f(a, 2, 5)` becomes `f_2_5(a)`, and so on.
In this way, every index interval is computed by a separate unique function.

Then you would end up with something like this, which I'm fairly sure you can understand, and your recursive solution works in the same way:

```
// These aren't all the functions, since there would be so many. 
// You get the point anyway.

float f_0_0(int a[]){
    if(0<0){
        return (f_0_0(a)+f_1_0(a))/2;
    }
    else 
        return a[0];
}

// ... Same for f_1_1 through f_5_5 ...

float f_6_6(int a[]){
    if(6<6){
        return (f_6_6(a)+f_7_6(a))/2;
    }
    else 
        return a[6];
}

float f_0_3(int a[]){
    if(0<3){
        return (f_0_1(a)+f_2_3(a))/2;
    }
    else 
        return a[0];
}

float f_4_6(int a[]){
    if(4<6){
        return (f_4_5(a)+f_6_6(a))/2;
    }
    else 
        return a[4];
}

float f_0_6(int a[]){
    if(0<6){
        return (f_0_3(a)+f_4_6(a))/2;
    }
    else 
        return a[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot for clearing things up. Cheers!!